# Extending People Picker to include form items like labels, input boxes and buttons

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I can finally use a people picker to update a SharePoint list.

How can I extend it to use form elements such as labels, buttons and input boxes?

I saw this code, but it underlines the `this.props.data.Name` with a message:

> property `data` does not exist on type 'readonly'.

It also underlines `onChange` saying it doesn't exist on type readonly.

```
    private _onChange = (e: React.KeyboardEvent) => {
       const name = this.props.data.Name;
       const value = (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
       this.props.onChange(name, value);
    }
```

This is the beginning of my class including the constructor.  I'm worried that if I add more properties to the interface, I could stop the people picker working.

```
     export default class PnPPeoplePicker extends React.Component<IPnPPeoplePickerProps, IPnPPeoplePickerState> {  
       constructor(props: IPnPPeoplePickerProps, state: IPnPPeoplePickerState) 
       {
         super(props);

         this.state = {
           addUsers: []
         };
       }
```

Comment: Do you have `data` property in your `IPnPPeoplePickerState` interface?

Comment: No.  Should the data property be in this interface or in a new interface?  What type should it be?

Comment: In your code, you are using `this.props.data.Name`. Does `this.props` has data property in it? If no then you need to add it in `IPnPPeoplePickerProps` interface in order to use it. Have you copied this code from somewhere else?

Comment: I used the zip file on https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pnp-people-picker-control-for-spfx/

Comment: I added data to the interface and amended the constructor as follows:    constructor(props: IPnPPeoplePickerProps, state: IPnPPeoplePickerState) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      addUsers: [],
      data:
    };
  }

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: It's saying Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }> & Readonly<IPnPPeoplePickerProps>'.ts.  Also I'm not sure what the type should be of the data variable in IpnpPeoplePicker state and therefore I don't know what to put in the constructor above.

Comment: I moved the data property to the props interface.  Now it's saying the Name property doesn't exist on type string.  What should be the type of data?

Comment: Why you are using data? I downloaded the zip from the link you provided and I think this code is not available in that package. Data should be an object with Name property `data:{Name:string}`

Comment: I thought it was necessary to extend what's in the zip to include other controls with the people picker eg labels, input boxes, text boxes and buttons.  If you have another way, please share it.

Comment: I'm trying to use this but my public render module has something different after the colon.  https://coderwall.com/p/irfj6g/value-of-input-field-react-typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the solution from here:

[SPFx React Form with People Picker/Taxonomy Picker using PnP Js & React Controls](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SPFx-React-Form-with-f3efaba5)